# Original design of DecreaseKey of Fibonacci heaps in Fredman and Tarjan's paper

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, fibonacci-heap

I am now implementing the Fibonacci heap according to the original [Paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=28874) of Fredman and Tarjan. If I understand it correctly, according to the paper, to perform the *DecreseKey* operation of a node *x*, we simply cut it from its parent. But if the key after decreasing is still larger than its parent, it would be inefficient (I think). Also, I see many designs that cut a node only when its key becomes smaller than its parent, like in CLRS.

So I am a bit confused about the original design of it. Why didn't they apply a more efficient way to do *DecreaseKey*. Or maybe it makes the amortised analysis easier? Any response is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Fredman and Tarjan (though I audited one of Tarjan's classes once), but presumably they were focused on the worst-case amortized complexity of DecreaseKey, on which that optimization has no effect.

Comment: Thank you, David! Yeah, that might be the case. It's just I found that the practical performance of two versions differs a lot. So I'm kinda curious about why they designed this way (although both yield the same amortized bound).

Comment: @Snjór It's simpler, and theoreticians largely only care about the theoretical worst-case anyway.